# Create date from day, month, year as integers in KDB Q

Tags: date, kdb

I am trying to get a date from its integer components: I have day, month and year as variables (that can change, I don't want to hard code them), and I want to reunite them in a date variable.

For example, something like that;

> myDay: 15
>
> myMonth: 4
>
> myYear: 2016

`` `date$(myYear,myMonth,myDay) `` --> should return 2016.4.15 (formatted as a date).

Any way to do that?
Thank you

Comment: First concate your variables and then convert it to Date.

Comment: How should I do that? Isn't it what I did here: `date$(myYear,myMonth,myDay) ?

Comment: No, concate it like a valid date format i.e 2016.04.15. when you get this then pass it to your date function to convert it to date.

Comment: http://help.pervasive.com/display/DI1028/Date,+Date$+Functions

Comment: `date$("." sv (string myDay ; string myMonth ; string myDay)) does not work. it returns a list of date. For the 2016.04.15 I get:
2000.02.20 2000.02.18 2000.02.19 2000.02.24 2000.02.16 2000.02.22 2000.02.16 2000.02.19 2000.02.23

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
q)d:3
q)m:8
q)y:2016
q)"D"$"." sv string (y;m;d)
    2016.08.03
```

See [cast](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/casting/#cast) vs [tok](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/casting/#tok) - need to use different arguments depending on if what you're casting from is a string or not